# Can I use retry interval minuts to deplay a step in Job in SQL SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have created a new job on sql and I have some steps, but I need need that the step 3 only starts 3hours after the step 2 has finished.
I was wondering if I could use retry interval minuts
[image]
However it seems that this only works if the step fails.

Is it possible use the retry interval minutes for my target or if not Is there any alternative?
Thanks

Comment: Is that SSMS or similar? Doesn't relate to the <sql> _language_ afaik.

Comment: Yes it is SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Retry interval minutes are only used when a job step is run and fails.

I would suggest a job step using the WAITFOR command:

```
`WAITFOR DELAY '03:00'`
```

Comment: As my step 3 with a sql script. Can i add `WAITFOR DELAY '03:00'` in the begginer of this scrip or I need to create a new step only with `WAITFOR DELAY '03:00'`?

Comment: Either would work. I'd be inclined to make it a separate step for logging purposes. If combined, the one step's execution time would include the wait period, as opposed to showing the time actually required to execute the step. (Sorry for the delayed response!)